# .htaccess RewriteRule not redirecting from real folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm still a bit fuzzy on the working of .htaccess, and I've looked around but I can't find anything to help this specific issue.

EDIT:  I realize there are other questions that seem like they cover this issue, but I checked some and they didn't seem to offer any help I could understand, and I didn't want to hijack them with my own issues.

This is what I have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /mp3/(.*) http://old.domain.com/mp3/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

As you can see from the last line, the string typed after the server name is actually a URL parameter and depending on that parameter, different content is pulled from the database and that page is displayed on the site.

The problem I'm having is that the client has a content page called "podcast", so they would go to `site.com/podcast` which should quietly redirect to `site.com/index.php?=podcast` and load the content for that page.  Unfortunately, the client also has a real `site.com/podcast/` folder on their server. Because of this, the rewrite is ignored and the browser attempts to load that folder.  It either shows a file listing or a forbidden error if I disable the listing.

After some research (I'm still new to htaccess), I learned that the two lines prior disable the rewrite if the path points to an actual file or folder.  Unfortunately, commenting out the one with `!-d` doesn't seem to have any effect, and commenting out both gives me a server error.

Admittedly, part of the problem here was lack of foresight.  URL rewrites should have been planned before everything else was put together, but it wasn't until the site was basically completed that I was notified that the client wants "Friendly URLs" that don't include the `?p=` part.  Regardless, perhaps there is a way to fix this.

Is there some .htaccess trickery I can use that will force the rewrite even if the URL entered points to a folder (not a specific file) that actually exists?  As stated before, removing the `!-d` doesn't seem to help, although I'm not sure why.  Perhaps I misunderstand its purpose.

Thank you for any help, and please be lenient with me if I overlooked something obvious.  This is an issue presenting itself on the client's live site right now so I feel a little rushed in solving it.  Thanks again.

OH YEAH, and the solution can't be specific to `/podcast`.  The way the client's site is set up, when they want to create a new subpage for the site, a new name is saved for that content based on their title for the page and it is possible (unlikely, but still possible) that another page can be created with a name that matches an existing folder on the server.

Comment: Can you access using site.com/index.php?=podcast normally?

Comment: Yes.  That works normally because it isn't pointing to the /podcast folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a note from [**mod_rewrite** documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions):

> By default, mod_rewrite will ignore URLs that map to a directory on
>   disk but lack a trailing slash, in the expectation that the mod_dir
>   module will issue the client with a redirect to the canonical URL with
>   a trailing slash.

This explains why mod_rewrite ignores the URL `/podcast`. I would suggest that you rename physical directories so that do do not (accidentally) match article names.

Another option would be to disable the [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) setting. This will prevent Apache from redirecting `/podcast` to `/podcast/`.

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

**Be warned that disabling this setting has side effects**. Read through the documentation first.

Comment: Thank you.  Temporarily, I simply created an `index.php` in the podcast folder so that instead of loading the file listing it would direct the visitor to the intended content.  My boss said that this was fine and that we wouldn't have to worry about it any more, so I take that as meaning he explained to the client that the URLs cannot match the folders.  However, this is all still good for learning, and I will accept your answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line of code:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(podcast([^?]*)) index.php?p=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This does this opposite of help.  It actually breaks all of the other URLs and yet `/podcast` still shows the directory listing.

Comment: Additionally, while a targeted fix will help for the time being, in the long run I am going to need a solution that will work for any folder, not just the one named 'podcast'.

Comment: There was somewhat wrong. Please try: RewriteRule ^(podcast([^?]*)) index.php?p=$1 [L,NC]

Comment: I appreciate this, but as I said I need something that will work with any matching folder, not just `podcast`

Comment: RewriteRule ^(podcast|folder1|folder2([^?]*)) index.php?p=$1 [L,NC]

Comment: Thanks, but it would need to be dynamic enough to match folders that cannot be predetermined.  In other words, we can't know what folders will exist in the future.